# Find point on line, given starting point and angle

Tags: trigonometry

I have a line and I know the starting point (0,0) and I know the angle between the line and the x-axis (30 degrees).  How would I be able to find another point (any other point, doesn't matter which) that lies on that line?

Answer (score 2):

Your line is given in polar coordinates by $\theta=30^\circ = \pi/6$. Let $r \neq 0$ be arbitrary, and take $(x,y) = (r\cos \theta, r \sin\theta)$. So for example, take $r=1$ and you'll get $(x,y) = (\sqrt{3}/2, 1/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the line is not vertical, you can just pick any $x$ and $(x,x \tan(angle))$ will be on the line.  This comes from the definition of tangent.

Comment: what if it is vertical?

Comment: @johnktejik:  If the line is vertical, it is the $y$ axis and any point $(0,y)$ is on the line